# Angular2: Can I generate style code in a external file , not style element?

Tags: angular

Why angular2 generate the style code in the head style element, not an external file.I want to bundle the style code in a bundle.css file, then link it in HTML head.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using angular CLI then you can define multiple external style sheet in **.angular-cli.json** file as follow.

```
"styles": [
    "styles.css",
    "xyz.css"
  ],
```

All the file define here will bundle in one single file when you run **ng build --prod** command.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So if I define component style,It must be written to head element?

Comment: Are you talking about specific component only style ?

Comment: Yes,I want to bundle all components style to a single file.Not in HTML head section

Comment: Component related style need to write in specific component that not need to define in head section.
For information check this link https://angular.io/guide/component-styles